# MongoDB Aggregation SUM Array of Arrays by object key

Tags: mongodb

Okay, so I've been searching for a while but couldn't find an answer to this, and I am desperate :P

I have some documents with this syntax

```
{
    "period": ISODate("2018-05-29T22:00:00.000+0000"),
    "totalHits": 13982
    "hits": [
        {
            // some fields...
            users: [
                { 
                    // some fields...
                    userId: 1,
                    products: [
                        { productId: 1, price: 30 },
                        { productId: 2, price: 30 },
                        { productId: 3, price: 30 },
                        { productId: 4, price: 30 },
                    ]
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And I want to retrieve a count of how many products (Independently of which user has them) we have on a period, an example output would be like this:

```
[
    {
        "period": ISODate("2018-05-27T22:00:00.000+0000"),
        "count": 432
    },
    {
        "period": ISODate("2018-05-28T22:00:00.000+0000"),
        "count": 442
    },
    {
        "period": ISODate("2018-05-29T22:00:00.000+0000"),
        "count": 519
    }
]
```

What is driving me crazy is the "object inside an array inside an array" I've done many aggregations but I think they were simpler than this one, so I am a bit lost.

I am thinking about changing our document structure to a better one, but we have ~6M documents which we would need to transform to the new one and that's just a mess... but Maybe it's the only solution.

We are using MongoDB 3.2, we can't update our systems atm (I wish, but not possible).

Comment: If you want that "per user id" then you have no other option than to `$unwind` each array whatever the version. Newer versions will not do anything for you here and the issue seems more with nesting arrays where you should really have a much flatter structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$unwind` to expand your array, then use `$group` to sum:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$match: {}}, 
    {$unwind: "$hits"}, 
    {$project: {_id: "$_id", period: "$period", users: "$hits.users"}}, 
    {$unwind: "$users"}, 
    {$project: {_id: "$_id", period: "$period", subCout: {$size: "$users.products"}}}, 
    {$group: {"_id": "$period", "count": {$sum: "$count"}}}
])
```

Comment: I've read unwind is not optimal for huge collections, anyway it takes super low to get the count, I need to check the results but it gives me a better result than aggregations I've tried, so I'll give you my feedback as soon as we test stuff, but looks promising :D (I will carve this aggr on my brain)

Comment: It looks like it is doing a SUM of all the products and not only the ones matching that ID, for example in our old data we have a count of 180 for a product, with this query I am getting a count of 8641, which is really huge and looks like the sum of every product (because our stock etc). I tried with $filter but I am not really good with it so is doing nothing :P (sum is always 0)

Comment: You have to place your filter here `{$match: {}},` and tailor as your need. If you want specific prodduct, place a `$match` after each projection.

Comment: Yeah, I placed my filter inside that match, `{"hits.users.products.productId": 1}` I think the `$sum $size` is the problem because the size of the `products` array doesn't only contains one product, but a bunch of them, I think it counts the size of the array if the document contains that product, not doing +1 to the count everytime that exact product inside hits exists (I think, I am going off now, I'll check again tomorrow morning) ^^